# Fetch to Wikipedia-api is not being made

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api, wikipedia-api

I'm doing the Wikipedia viewer from FCC projects with React, I'm trying to make the request by just passing it the `searchQuery` (from my state) with template string. Like this:

```
gettingArticle() {
  const { searchQuery, articlesList } = this.state;

  const API = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=${searchQuery}&prop=info&inprop=url&utf8=&format=json`;

  const body = { method: 'GET', dataType: 'json'};

  const myRequest = new Request(API, body);
  fetch(myRequest)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ 
      articlesList: data, articles: true }));
  console.log( 'data fetched' + displayedArticles);
}
```

I don't know for sure if is like this that I have to made the request it's just what I saw on the docs. I want to made the request and after receive the data I want to iterate over the array of objects and put every little thing that I need in their corresponding tag inside a div. Here is my entire code: https://codepen.io/manAbl/pen/VxQQyJ?editors=0110

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you missed a key details in the API documentation

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests

> Unauthenticated CORS requests may be made from any origin by setting the "origin" request parameter to "*". In this case MediaWiki will include the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false header in the response and will process the request as if logged out (in case credentials are somehow sent anyway).

So I update your url like below

```
const API = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&list=search&srsearch=${searchQuery}&prop=info&inprop=url&utf8=&format=json`;
```

And also your `console.log` was at the wrong place, so I changed it to below

```
fetch(myRequest)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
    console.log( 'data fetched', data);

    this.setState({ 
      articlesList: data, articles: true })
                  });
```

Below is a updates pen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxMyxX?editors=0110

And now you can see the `API` call works

[image: Working]

Of course I didn't check why you have white strip after the call is successful, but that may be something wrong you do in your React code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not really in your code but in CORS, basically you are not allowed to make the call because of same origin policy.

Change these 2 constants

```
const API = `https://crossorigin.me/https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=${searchQuery}&prop=info&inprop=url&utf8=&format=json`;

const body = { method: 'GET', dataType: 'json', mode: 'cors', cache: 'default'};
```

I added crossorigin url before your API because it 'overrides' CORS and enables you to make calls outside the same origin policy. You should also modify your submit function:

```
handleSubmit(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault(); //This disables default form function (reload/redirect of website and loss of state)
   this.gettingArticle();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but still doesn't work now it doesn't refresh the page but neither make the api call